# Why doesn't Sencha Touch 2 have an xtype displayfield?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

If you look in Ext documentation there is an xtype displayfield, but not in Sencha Touch. Is there is a replacement for displayfield in Sencha Touch2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short story short. No there is not such component in Sencha Touch.

But I'm sure you can easily replace it with simple pure HTML.

Comment: Yeah, I used the field xtype and set the value with the html property.

Answer (score 0):

You can use textfield and disable him:

`yourTextField.setReadOnly(false);`

Comment: That is what I did initially but the text gets clipped and does not wrap.

Comment: I already tried textarea field, but by default sencha sets 3 rows. So you can have a one line sentence with two extra rows following.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own displayfield by extending '**Ext.field.Field**' and using '**Ext.Component**'.
Create a view '**DisplayField**'

```
Ext.define('<yourAppName>.view.DisplayField', {
    extend: 'Ext.field.Field',
    xtype: 'displayfield',
    requires: ['<yourAppName>.view.DisplayFieldComponent'],
    config: {
        component: {
            xtype: 'displayFieldComponent'
        }
    },
    setValue: function (value) {
       this.getComponent().displayElement.setHtml(value);
        return this;
    }
});
```

Create another view '**DisplayFieldComponent**'

```
Ext.define('<yourAppName>.view.DisplayFieldComponent', {
    extend: 'Ext.Component',
    xtype: 'displayFieldComponent',
    config: {
        cls: 'x-field-input'
    },
    getTemplate: function () {
        return [
            {
                reference: 'displayElement',
                tag: 'div',
                style: 'padding:4px'//style it in your own way
            }
        ];
    },
   });
```

Add the '**DisplayField**' in views object of you app configuration

```
views:[
'DisplayField'
]
```

Now use it in your other views by giving the **xtype:'displayfield'**